# Weight Generation in Java

Tags: java

I am pretty new to Java and programing in general. I was hoping someone could please explain how I could generate a series of weights across N objects. For example imagine you had to select the proportion of cash you wanted to invest in IBM stock vs AIG stock. In the simple 2 stock case I used the for-loop

```
    for(int i = 0; i <101; i++){
        double creditWieght = i*allocationIncrement;
        double traditionalWeight = 1-creditWieght;
        actionSet.add(new Pair(creditWieght,traditionalWeight));

    }
```

which for the `LinkHashSet actionSet` gives the output

```
[< 0.0 , 1.0 > , < 0.01 , 0.99 > , < 0.02 , 0.98 > , < 0.03 , 0.97 > , < 0.04 , 0.96 > , < 0.05 , 0.95 > , < 0.06 , 0.94 > , < 0.07 , 0.9299999999999999 > , < 0.08 , 0.92 > , < 0.09 , 0.91 > , < 0.1 , 0.9 > , < 0.11 , 0.89 > , < 0.12 , 0.88 > , < 0.13 , 0.87 > , < 0.14 , 0.86 > , < 0.15 , 0.85 > , < 0.16 , 0.84 > , < 0.17 , 0.83 > , < 0.18 , 0.8200000000000001 > , < 0.19 , 0.81 > , < 0.2 , 0.8 > , < 0.21 , 0.79 > , < 0.22 , 0.78 > , < 0.23 , 0.77 > , < 0.24 , 0.76 > , < 0.25 , 0.75 > , < 0.26 , 0.74 > , < 0.27 , 0.73 > , < 0.28 , 0.72 > , < 0.29 , 0.71 > , < 0.3 , 0.7 > , < 0.31 , 0.69 > , < 0.32 , 0.6799999999999999 > , < 0.33 , 0.6699999999999999 > , < 0.34 , 0.6599999999999999 > , < 0.35000000000000003 , 0.6499999999999999 > , < 0.36 , 0.64 > , < 0.37 , 0.63 > , < 0.38 , 0.62 > , < 0.39 , 0.61 > , < 0.4 , 0.6 > , < 0.41000000000000003 , 0.59 > , < 0.42 , 0.5800000000000001 > , < 0.43 , 0.5700000000000001 > , < 0.44 , 0.56 > , < 0.45 , 0.55 > , < 0.46 , 0.54 > , < 0.47000000000000003 , 0.53 > , < 0.48 , 0.52 > , < 0.49 , 0.51 > , < 0.5 , 0.5 > , < 0.51 , 0.49 > , < 0.52 , 0.48 > , < 0.53 , 0.47 > , < 0.54 , 0.45999999999999996 > , < 0.55 , 0.44999999999999996 > , < 0.56 , 0.43999999999999995 > , < 0.5700000000000001 , 0.42999999999999994 > , < 0.58 , 0.42000000000000004 > , < 0.59 , 0.41000000000000003 > , < 0.6 , 0.4 > , < 0.61 , 0.39 > , < 0.62 , 0.38 > , < 0.63 , 0.37 > , < 0.64 , 0.36 > , < 0.65 , 0.35 > , < 0.66 , 0.33999999999999997 > , < 0.67 , 0.32999999999999996 > , < 0.68 , 0.31999999999999995 > , < 0.6900000000000001 , 0.30999999999999994 > , < 0.7000000000000001 , 0.29999999999999993 > , < 0.71 , 0.29000000000000004 > , < 0.72 , 0.28 > , < 0.73 , 0.27 > , < 0.74 , 0.26 > , < 0.75 , 0.25 > , < 0.76 , 0.24 > , < 0.77 , 0.22999999999999998 > , < 0.78 , 0.21999999999999997 > , < 0.79 , 0.20999999999999996 > , < 0.8 , 0.19999999999999996 > , < 0.81 , 0.18999999999999995 > , < 0.8200000000000001 , 0.17999999999999994 > , < 0.8300000000000001 , 0.16999999999999993 > , < 0.84 , 0.16000000000000003 > , < 0.85 , 0.15000000000000002 > , < 0.86 , 0.14 > , < 0.87 , 0.13 > , < 0.88 , 0.12 > , < 0.89 , 0.10999999999999999 > , < 0.9 , 0.09999999999999998 > , < 0.91 , 0.08999999999999997 > , < 0.92 , 0.07999999999999996 > , < 0.93 , 0.06999999999999995 > , < 0.9400000000000001 , 0.05999999999999994 > , < 0.9500000000000001 , 0.04999999999999993 > , < 0.96 , 0.040000000000000036 > , < 0.97 , 0.030000000000000027 > , < 0.98 , 0.020000000000000018 > , < 0.99 , 0.010000000000000009 > , < 1.0 , 0.0 > ]
```

However, I'm not sure how I would go about expanding this to `N weights`.

Can anyone help please?

Thanks in advance

Comment: First pen down an algorithm for your task and then try to implement that algorithm

Answer (score 0):

I had completely forgot about this post after I figured out a number of solutions a couple of weeks after I posted the question. Only noticing it again after a posting on R earlier today. The solutions below are based on attempts I had made before I posted the question looking for advice.

Essentially, there are a number of way to build a set of N>3 weightings. The ones that worked best were:

Approach 1: Time consuming if N is large

1: define a temporary double array of length N
2: define a LinkHashSet or other HashMap to collect the temporary arrays
3: generate successive random numbers between 0 and 1 and populated the temporary array created in step 1 and insert into successive elements of the array making sure that each successive weight (x) meets the condition 
x(i) < (1-sum(x(0,....i-1)) and sum(x(0,....i)<1
4: where the array elements sum up to 1 (i.e. sum(x(0,....i)=1) add the array to the LinkHashSet/HashMap defined in step 2 with some indexing key int making sure to check that no other array already exists in the LinkHashSet with the same permutation of values in its elements
5: repeat till a large enough number of sets of weights have been generated

Approach 2:less accurate population size but faster than Approach 1

1: set to be divisible by 3 or 4 and define a LinkHashSet/HashMap to store the weights and ArrayList for convenience when generating the weights
2: define the weights for 3 or 4 assets. This is fairly straight forward for an average human brain to get around store in the ArrayList
3: now treat each of the 4 computed weights as a class of asset with weight x computed in step 2 and generate another set of 3 or 4 weights and multiply each new weight by the weight in step 2 and add to or update the ArrayList as appropriate
4: repeat till step 3 for each element of the ArrayList using the updated weights in the ArrayList from the previous round of step 3 till the size of the ArrayList is N
5: store the ArrayList in a LinkHashSet/HashMap with an indexing key for easy recall

Answer (score -1):

I did not have any experience in this kind of stuff but i think if you use enamurations  you can overcome with this problem.but im not sure :)

Comment: scofield good suggestion but it would have been too complicated using enumerations. I did figure out the solution(s) which I will vaguely describe in case anyone else has the same question.